# Getting an error while enabling popup

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

I am new to this stuff. Basically I am trying to show the data from my local database in the popup for some specific rivers, but I am having a hard time while enabling popup. I tried to find the solution but didn't find anything.

I am using `Esri_Hydro_Reference_Overlay` layer to show rivers in this [map](https://arcg.is/1LSnbL) and I am getting this message:

[image]

the next message says

> This layer doesn't have any attribute data. You can, however, display attributes from a different feature layer in the pop-up.
>   How do you want to specify what layer to use?

And it gives me two options

> Choose from my items

and

> Enter a URL for a layer

here is the Screenshot of it

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you adding the same URL for the hydro reference layer? If the layer is a Tile Layer(I am guessing cached map service in this case) you wont get popups from that layer. If you have a feature layer(Feature Service) you can use that to drive the popups for that layer.

Comment: yes it is a tile layer. any way to show popups in it?

Comment: You will have to use a feature layer(in this case of rivers) to drive the popups for this tile layer. So when you click on the tile layer its able to send a query of that location through to the feature layer "behind" the tile layer being displayed in the map. You cannot use a tile layer to drive the popup.

Comment: so how should i do this implementation? Anything would be a big help

Comment: You will need to find or publish a feature layer of river data that matches what you see in the tile layer that is the area you are interested in. Then follow the popup workflow that you have in the initial post where you use a layer from My Items or through a URL of the feature layer(feature service).

Comment: thank you i am looking forward to it and that's a great help i appreciate your response.

Comment: Can I fetch my own pop-up content in this map? Does it need feature layer?

Comment: yes it needs a feature layer or another layer that supports querying for content like WMS.